# parse json objects from a log file

Tags: java, json

I want to parse the JSON objects from my log file. For using JSON Parser my complete files has to be in JSON format which is not the case with me. Is there any way I can parse the file line by line and get the JSON objects.
Below is my log file format:

```
2015-10-19 11:24:35:701 INFO  BrokerTcpClient:28 - Set destination 
2015-10-19 11:24:35:929 DEBUG BrokerTcpClient:32 - received data: {type=data,  payload={

    "core" : [ {
      "id" : {
        "datatype" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/hk#long",
        "type" : "gh",
        "value" : "gh"
      },
      "entity" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://fg.fg.com/ext/g/fg"
      },
      "Sno" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "fg"
      }]
2015-10-19 11:24:35:701 INFO  BrokerTcpClient:28 - Set destination 
2015-10-19 11:24:35:929 DEBUG BrokerTcpClient:32
    "core" : [ {
      "id" : {
        "datatype" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/hk#long",
        "type" : "gh",
        "value" : "gh"
      },
      "entity" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://fg.fg.com/ext/g/fg"
      },
      "Sno" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "fg"
      }]
```

Can any one please help how should I get my JSON objects. When I am trying to parse a single line of JSON objects throwing an exception.

Comment: The log has a specific format, so you just need to strip out what you don't care about:  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:mmm <eventLevel> <Object>:<Line>

Comment: Sorry I did not get you.. What i understood is read line by line.. and where i find my data to store it in any collection? Please guide me if i am wrong

Comment: Even stripping away the time stamped log data the json in your example is not valid. You have 1 unclosed { in the first "json" so you would not only need to parse out the attempted json, but also close the unclosed { or [.

Comment: You could iterate through each line and if the current line doesn't start with a time stamp when the last did assume the current line is part of a json object and continue adding lines to the object string until you hit another time stamp then wrap that object in {} to make it valid json

Comment: Sorry Thats my copy paste mistake. json objects are valid in log file with complete end braces too. So i should add one json object in one string object, and parse it using json parser. will try it. but my log file is very big, So i was avoiding this approach

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for the sample log that is posted.

```
import java.io.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
public class JSONTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String logFilename = "C://Temp/sample.log";
        String line, json = "";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logFilename))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (isLogLine(line)) {
                    if (!json.isEmpty()) {
                        parseJson(json);
                        json = "";
                    }
                } else {
                    json += line;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isLogLine(String line) {
        return line.matches("^\\d{4}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{3}.+$");
    }

    public static void parseJson(String json) throws Exception {
        if (!json.startsWith("{") && !json.endsWith("}")) json = "{" + json + "}";
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(om.readValue(fixJson(json), Object.class));
    }

    public static String fixJson(String json) {
        return "{" + json.replace("}]", "}}]") + "}";
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. the regex that identifies log line is checking for timestamp at the
   begining of the line. this will not work in case the log message
   spans multiple lines (for example if the message contains new line)
2. there is a method that attempts to "fix" the incomplete json from the log file, it may need additional logic, if there are more cases of incomplete json along the way
3. I used Jackson Json parser and let ObjectMapper figure out what data structure to parse into

Comment: I tried. Able to separate the json objects from log file into a string, but when i am trying to parse it using JSONParser. Exception is coming: "Unexpected token at 8";
Why it is. I am not getting is this not the json proper format. Please help.

Comment: that is why I deliberately created `fixJson()` method so you can "play" with the string and fix it before it is parsed. the full exception message includes the json input so you can see what's wrong with the 8th character. if you post the FULL exception message, I can help

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into logstash (https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash)? It can solve this problem and perhaps other problems you will come across when trying to parse logs.